# Issue found: Missing “isMonitoringTool” flag

Tags: google-play, google-play-console, playback

[image]Am facing an issue regarding

Issue found: Missing “isMonitoringTool” flag

```
<manifest>
<meta-data android:name="isMonitoringTool" android:value="enterprise_management" />
<application>
<meta-data android:name="isMonitoringTool" android:value="enterprise_management" />
</application>
</manifest>
```

But the App got rejected again and again.

Please help us regarding this issue.

As Per this Answer by Google Play
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/12955211?sjid=14359500940746883129-AP

We made multiple changes but everytime app got rejected.

Detailed Error

```
Issue found: Missing “isMonitoringTool” flag
We found that your app is not compliant with the Stalkerware and Monitoring Applications policy since the “isMonitoringTool” flag is not declared in your app’s manifest file(s).

To bring your app into compliance, follow these steps:

Read the instructions in our Help Center to declare the “isMonitoringTool” flag value in your app’s manifest file(s).
After making the required updates, deactivate the non-compliant version, upload a compliant version with an incremented version code and make a new submission.
If you have any concerns with this assessment, please contact our policy support team and provide details.
About the Stalkerware and Monitoring Applications policy
Starting May 2023, your app must be in compliance with Google Play’s Stalkerware and Monitoring Applications policy or your app may face additional enforcement actions.

According to Google Play’s Stalkerware and Monitoring Applications policy, apps exclusively designed and marketed for monitoring another individual, for example, parents to monitor their children or enterprise management for the monitoring of individual employees, provided they fully comply with the requirements described below are the only acceptable monitoring apps. These apps cannot be used to track anyone else (a spouse, for example) even with their knowledge and permission, regardless if persistent notification is displayed. These apps must use the "isMonitoringTool" metadata flag in their manifest file to appropriately designate themselves as monitoring apps.

Monitoring apps must provide adequate prominent disclosure and obtain consent as required by the User Data policy. Additionally, they must comply with the following requirements:
Apps must not present themselves as a spying or secret surveillance solution.
Apps must not hide or cloak tracking behavior or attempt to mislead users about such functionality.
Apps must present users with a persistent notification at all times when the app is running and a unique icon that clearly identifies the app.
Apps must disclose monitoring or tracking functionality in the Google Play store description.
Apps and app listings on Google Play must not provide any means to activate or access functionality that violate these terms, such as linking to a noncompliant APK hosted outside Google Play.
Apps must comply with any applicable laws. You are solely responsible for determining the legality of your app in its targeted locale.
```